# Springboard freeze issue on iPhone - During Frank automation

Tags: iphone, ios, cucumber, ui-automation, frank

This is what I am doing,

- Installing my test App using Fruitstrap on the test iPhone
- Running Frank automation on the App
- Un-installing the App using Fruitstrap,

Now when I try to repeat the above process, on 2nd iteration I am experiencing a Springboard freeze in the iPhone device. No apps can be invoked from iPhone, the device freezes completely and the device console log says "Sprinboard freeze"

Any suggestions ?

I am just using an iPhone4 and on iOS6, but issue exists even on iPhone4S

Comment: You device is probably out of memory. Make sure to kill other applications before running your tests. It might be caused by fruitstrap. Do you know which step triggers the freeze?

Comment: Uninstall and re-install creates the Spring board freeze.